# How to make a calculator in c++ using if else and functions?

Tags: c++

I am a new contributor and here I am trying to make a simple calculator but having errors in my code. When I compile the code I get:

```
Error: C:\Users\IJLAL\Documents\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status while compiling
```

In case it could help, here is the screen shot of error when I pressed compile button or F11 in Dev C++:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(float a, float b); 
int main()
{   
    float a, b, sum, sub, mul, divide, mod;
    char op;

    //operands and operators are enterd by the user
    cout<<"Enter any two operands with operator=";
    cin>>a>>op>>b;
    fun(a, b);
    return 0;
}
void op(float a, float b)
{
    if(a+b)
    {
        float sum=a+b;
        cout<<"\nAddition of two numbers is="<<sum;
    }
    else if(a-b)
    {
        float sub=a-b;
        cout<<"\nSubtraction of two numbers is="<<sub;
    }
    else if(a*b)
    {
        float mul=a*b;
        cout<<"\nMultiplication of two numbers is="<<mul;
    }
    else if(a/b)
    {
        float divide=a/b;
        cout<<"\nDivision of two number is="<<divide;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nInvalid operator.......";
    }
}
```

Please tell me the solution of this problem, so that I can compile the code successfully. If there is any better solution to make a simple calculator on **beginner level** please mention it in answer.

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: `if(a+b)` this is not what you want.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Too many. That code is almost hopelessly flawed and wrong.

Comment: You should not name a function the same name as a variable that you want to use in the same scope.

Comment: Your function should take the operator as a parameter. And use that in your if () or a switch

Comment: Error:   C:\Users\IJLAL\Documents\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: This ld linker error is because you call a function fun() that is defined nowhere (you only defined the function op())

Comment: @IjlalHussain `if(a+b)` -- What was your intent in this code?  What do you suspect this line does?  Advice -- every line of C++ you write, you must know what it does.  Yes, it is possible that the program will have bugs, but that also means that you know exactly what each line of code you write is intended to do.  Never throw random lines of code around, hoping it does what you feel it's supposed to do.  What will wind up happening is that the code may be valid C++, but is clearly not what is intended.

Comment: Read up on *lexing* and *parsing* as well as *abstract syntax tree*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use additional functions to make a better calculator. You can use this code. Hope this code will be helpful for you.

The header `<iomanip>` is part of the Input/output library of the `C++` Standard Library and `<math.h>` is used when we perform mathematical operations.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
  char op;
using namespace std;
void sum()
   {

    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    int numberitems;
    cout << "Enter number of items: \n";
    cin >> numberitems;

    for(int i=0;i<numberitems;i++)
    {
        cout<< "Enter number "<<i<<":\n\n" ;
        cin>>n; 
        sum+=n;
    }
    cout<<"sum is: "<< sum<<endl<<endl;

    }
void diff()
    {
     int diff;
     int n1,n2;
     cout<<"enter two numbers to find their difference:\n\n";
     cout<<"enter first number:";
     cin>>n1;
     cout<<"\nenter second number:";
     cin>>n2;
     diff=n1-n2;
     cout<<"\ndifference is:"<<diff<<endl<<endl;
     }

void pro()

    {
     int pro=1;
     int n;
     int numberitems;
     cout<<"enter number of items:\n";
     cin>>numberitems;
     for(int i=0;i<=numberitems;i++)
     {
             cout<<"\nenter item "<<i<<":";
             cin>>n;
             pro*=n;
     }

     cout<<"product is:"<<pro<<endl<<endl;    
     }

 void div()
     {
      int div;
      int n1;
      int n2;
      cout<<"enter 2 numbers to find their quotient\n\n";
      cout<<"enter numerator:";
      cin>>n1;
      cout<<"\nenter denominator:";
      cin>>n2;
      div=n1/n2;
      cout<<"\nquotient is:"<<div<<endl<<endl;
      }      

void power()
     {     
     long int p;
     int res=1,n; 
     cout<<"enter number:";
     cin>>n;
     cout<<"\nenter power:";
     cin>>p;
     for(int i=1;i<=p;i++)
     {
      res=n*res;
     }
      cout<<n<<"\n power "<<p<<" is :"<<res<<endl;
     } 

void sq()
     {
     float s;
     int n;
     cout<<"enter number to find its square root:";
     cin>>n;
     s=sqrt(n);
     cout<<"\nsquare root of "<<n<<" is :"<<s<<endl;
     }
 void fact()
     {
      long int f=1;
      int c=1,n;
      cout<<"enter number to find its factorial:";
      cin>>n;
      while(c<=n)
      {
                 f=f*c;
                 c+=1;
      }     
                 cout<<"\nfactorial of "<<n<<" is :"<<f<<endl;     
      }
void expo()
     {
          long double res=1,p; 
     double e=2.718281828;     
     cout<<"enter power of exponential function:";
     cin>>p;
     for(int i=1;i<=p;i++)
     {
      res=e*res;
     }
      cout<<" e^ "<<p<<" is :"<<res<<endl;

           }
int main()
{   


    system("cls");
    do
    {

    system("pause");              
    system("cls");    
    cout<<"***which operation you want to perform***\n";
    cout<<"press 0 for exit\n";
    cout<<"press 1 for addition \n";
    cout<<"press 2 for subtraction\n";
    cout<<"press 3 for multiplication\n";
    cout<<"press 4 for division\n";
    cout<<"press 5 for power calculation\n";
    cout<<"press 6 for square root \n";
    cout<<"press 7 for factorial calculation\n";
    cout<<"press 8 for exponential calculation\n";
    cout<<"press option:";
    cin>>op;
    switch(op)
    {
              case '1':
              sum();

              break;
              case '2':
              diff();
              break;
              case '3':
              pro();
              break;
              case '4':
              div();
              break;
              case '5':
              power();
              break;
              case '6':
              sq();
              break;
              case '7':
              fact();
              break;
              case '8':
              expo();
              break;     
              case '0':
              exit(0);    
              default:
              cout<<"invalid input"  ;
              system("cls");
    } 
    }

    while(op!='0');

                    getch();
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not so far from a result.  The problem is that you have not defined the function `fun()`.  Furthermore, in the function `op()` that you have defined, you do not use the operator of the input.

So first thing to do is to change the signature of the function:

```
void fun(char op, float a, float b);
```

Then you need to invoke your function in `main()`, passing also the  operation that was requested by the user:

```
fun(op, a, b);
```

Finally you need to change all your `if` to check if `op` is the matching operator:

```
void fun(char op, float a, float b)
{
    if(op=='+')
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(op=='-')
    {
...
```

You should then get the expected result.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/pJk1jk)

**Aditional infos**

- `if (a+b)` just calculates the expression using the two values of the user, and if it's non zero, it's considered as true.
- once you got this program to work, you can look for the `switch` statement

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm still a newbie on c++ but hope this would help, I used while loop to loop the calculator but I don't have a good error handler for example when users try to input a letter instead of numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int result (int a, int b, char op);

int main()
{


char optr, choice;
int nr1, nr2;

while (true){
cout << "Enter first number: ";
cin >> nr1;
cout << "Enter an operator (+ - / * %) : ";
cin >> optr;
cout << "Enter second number: ";
cin >> nr2;

result (nr1, nr2, optr);
cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N): ";
cin >> choice;

if (choice =='N'||choice =='n'){
    break;
    }
}

}


int result (int a, int b, char op)
{
int result;

if (op == '+'){
result = a + b;
cout << "Result to " << a << " + " << b << " = " << result << endl;
} else if (op == '-'){
result = a - b;
cout << "Result to " << a << " + " << b << " = " << result << endl;
} else if (op == '*'){
result = a * b;
cout << "Result to " << a << " * " << b << " = " << result << endl;
} else if (op == '/'){
result = a / b;
a / b;
cout << "Result to " << a << " / " << b << " = " << result << endl;
} else if (op == '%'){
result = a % b;
cout << "Remainder to " << a << " % " << b << " = " << result << endl;
} else {
cout <<"Error 404: " << a << op << b <<" Wrong input format. Program terminated."          << endl;


// i still dont know how to properly use error handling

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I won't criticize your solution as I have a better solution as you mentioned **"please mention a better solution in answer"**
Here's my solution with comments to make you understand what each statement does.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
// I am  going to show How to Design a program
// We have to break down our progress a bit by bit
// and do the progress of one thing with function
// For calculator we have to take input from user keyboard twice,
// And an opperator from user
int userInput() // this requires to get input from user keyboard
{
 cout << "Enter a number: ";
 int no{};
 cin >> no;
 return no;
}
char userOpr() // Using type char to store the ASCI Opperator means requires char to store +,*,/,-
{
 cout << "Enter opperator: ";
 char opr{};
 cin >> opr;
 return opr;
}
int calculate(int input1, char opper, int input2)
{
 if (opper == '+')
 {
 return input1 + input2;
 }
 else if (opper == '-')
 {
 return input1 - input2;
 }
 else if (opper == '*')
 {
 return input1 * input2;
 }
 else if (opper == '/')
 {
 return input1 / input2;
 }
 return 0;
}
int main()
{
 // get the first no. from user
 // getUserInput();
 // get the math oppperator from the user
 // getMathOpperator();
 // get the second no. from the user
 // getUserInput();
 // calculate the values
 // calculateResults();
 // print out the results
 // printResults();
 cout << "Hello This is a simple calculator program Designed by Shankhui!\n\n";
 while (true)
 {
 int input1{ userInput() };
 int input2{ userInput() };
 char opper{ userOpr() }; // Using type char to store the ASCI Opperator means requires char to store +,*,/,-
 cout << input1 << " " << opper << " " << input2 << " = " << calculate(input1, opper, input2) << '\n' << '\n';
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this code and modify however you want to.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {    

int math_ques_1, math_ques_2;

std::cout << "What is the base of the question?" << std::endl;

std::cin >> math_ques_1;

std::cout << "What do you want to add to the base?" << std::endl;

std::cin >> math_ques_2;

std::cout << "The answer is " << math_ques_1 + math_ques_2 << "." << std::endl; }
```

Comment: nice effort @CalvinS2R